# Comment functionality in Rails. undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

One thing I could never do properly is implement a comment feature. I'm not leaving my computer until I learn to do it.

The error is thrown on this line:

```
<strong><%= comment.user.first_name %></strong>
```

Apparently `user` is `nil`; but why? And what do I have to do to get this to work?

A comment should belong to a guide and a user. Users and guides both have many comments.

I started with

```
rails g scaffold comment body:text guide:references user:references
```

and then migrated the database. I completed the model associations as well.

Here is my guides controller show action:

```
  def show
    @guide = Guide.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @guide.comments.build
  end
```

Here is the part of the Guide show view that deals with comments:

```
<h3>Comments</h3>

<% @guide.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <div>
    <strong><%= comment.user.first_name %></strong>
    <br />
    <p><%= comment.body %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

Here is the comment form partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :body %>
    <%= f.association :user %>
    <%= f.association :guide %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:recoverable,
          :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :runescape_username, presence: true

  has_many :guides
  has_many :comments

  acts_as_voter

  def user_score
    self.guides.inject(0) { |sum, guide| sum += guide.score }
  end
end
```

Comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :guide
end
```

Comments controller create action:

```
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you post your `Comment` and `User` model code?

Comment: Posted requested information. @SrikanthVenugopalan

Comment: please paste your action where you are creating commnets

Comment: Posted requested information @NitinJ

Comment: put this delegate :name, :to => :user, :allow_nil => true in comment.rb

Comment: Where am I putting that? @NitinJ

Comment: <%= comment.user.try(:first_name) %>  after that see the solution of @Ch4rAss for saving user

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44772/discussion-between-nitinj-and-dylan-richards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line

```
@comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
```

with

```
@comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
```

in your `Comments#create` action.

You get this error because you don't assign `current_user` to created `Comment`. That's why `comment.user` returns `nil`.

As stated by AndreDurao, you can also validate user_id presence in `Comment` model, like this:

```
class Comment
  validates_presence_of :user
  # ...
end
```

Comment: The error is even occurring on the page when 0 comments are present, though.

Comment: You can also add a validation on model Comment to ensure user_id presence.

Comment: @Marek Lipka according to convention you should do validates_presence_of :user not user_id otherwise you can assign a non exist user_id such as 23455 to comment

Answer (score 0):

for getting rid of that error try this `<%= comment.user.try(:first_name) %>`